# MS Test unit testing framework Won't Hit its Constructor

Tags: c#, mstest

My MSTest test class does contain constructor to initialize logging functionality specific variables.
When running unit test methods in debug mode, found that my debugger is not hitting my constructor. Since we can use `[TestInitialize]` method in MSTest to force this method to execute before executing any of the methods, I've created `Startup()` method for this purpose. Even now, debugger is not hitting this method. Hence, all my test methods are failing.

Can anyone please point me where I'm doing wrong! Any suggestions to resolve this issue please...

```
[TestClass]
public class AutomaticInformationUpdateTest
{
    private readonly ILogger<AutomaticInformationUpdate> _logger;
    private static ILoggerFactory _loggerFactory;
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    //ISSUE: When executing individual methods, or complete test class, this constructor is not calling
    public AutomaticInformationUpdateTest(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _loggerFactory = loggerFactory;
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        _logger = _loggerFactory.CreateLogger<AutomaticInformationUpdate>();
    }

    // ISSUE: I should not use this method as I cannot initialize most of the private variables.
    // Even then, I tried this method with the hope that the debugger can can this method.
    // Debugger is not hitting even for this method.
    [TestInitialize]
    public void Startup()
    {
        _logger = _loggerFactory.CreateLogger<AutomaticInformationUpdate>();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void ProcessFullEngineInformation_Test()
    {
        IAutomaticInformationUpdate updater = new AutomaticInformationUpdate(_loggerFactory, _serviceProvider);
        Assert.IsTrue(updater.ProcessFullInformation().GetAwaiter().GetResult()); 
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void ProcessIncrimentalEngineInformation_Test()
    {
        IAutomaticInformationUpdate updater = new AutomaticInformationUpdate(_loggerFactory, _serviceProvider);
        Assert.IsTrue(updater.ProcessIncrimentalInformation().GetAwaiter().GetResult());
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void ProcessLvlFullInformation_Test()
    {
        IAutomaticInformationUpdate updater = new AutomaticInformationUpdate(_loggerFactory, _serviceProvider);
        Assert.IsTrue(updater.ProcessLvlFull().GetAwaiter().GetResult());
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void ProcessLvlIncrimentalInformation_Test()
    {
        IAutomaticInformationUpdate updater = new AutomaticInformationUpdate(_loggerFactory, _serviceProvider);
        Assert.IsTrue(updater.ProcessLvlIncrimental().GetAwaiter().GetResult());
    }
}
```

Comment: did you re-compile your project?

Comment: @HimBromBeere: Yes, I recompiled and executed test methods number of times.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the ol' turn it off and on again? You'd be amazed by how much [caching the VS IDE does](https://errorhandlinginskills.wordpress.com/2018/07/28/how-to-clear-visual-studio-cache/). While I'm not advocating for deleting individual cached files, I would try restarting the IDE, clean the solution, and retry. Your code looks fine to me.

You might want to confirm breakpoints are being hit anywhere by setting them in your test methods. This would tell you if your debugging setup is broken.